# CXF log4j doesn't work since migrating from cxf 2.2.3 to 2.7.17

Tags: java, log4j, cxf

We recently migrated from CXF 2.2.3 to CXF2.7.17 and i don't see anymore any cxf logs in the log file they are supposed to go to.

As far as i know our configuration to log CXF is pretty standard.

In the cxf.xml we have

```
<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound" />
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound" />
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound" />
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

The tomcat (7 with java 7) is launched with the parameter :

```
-Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

And in our lo4g prop file :

```
log4j.appender.cxfAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.cxfAppender.file=/usr/users/theuser/DATA/LOG/theappli-web/theappli-CXF.log
log4j.appender.cxfAppender.layout=com.thefirm.log.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cxfAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%D %h TOMCAT[-%C{1}] : %X{UTILISATEUR}-%X{JSESSIONID};%p;%M;ESV;%X{CODE_MSG};%m;;%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor=INFO, cxfAppender
log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf.interceptor=false
```

Nothing has changed in these files during the migration. Has anyone faced the same problem after migrating ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer in the cxf migration log.

> The Logging interceptors now log using service specific categories/loggers >instead of just LoggingInInterceptor/LoggingOutInterceptor. The names of the >logger that is used is
>   org.apache.cxf.services.ServiceName.PortName.PortTypeName. This allows the user >to configure specific per service filters and formatters in their logging >configuration

The solution was to replace `log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor=INFO, cxfAppender`with `log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.=INFO, cxfAppender`.